# Several unicode characters are not displaying on many big sites (like this: ⁠)

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, unicode

There are several Unicode charactes I'm just seeing as boxes. This happens in Chrome only. The Character Encoding is set to UTF-8, but Autodetection doesn't help.

**Example:** [⁠]

You will only see two square brackets, but actually there is the Unicode Character [*World Joiner*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2060/index.htm) in between. It's a zero-width non-breaking space.

I also put together a little [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eLzWv/). I can't see the *World Joiner* character, but I can see the *Hair Space*. (And by seeing it I actually mean I don't see it. You see?)

This also happens when people post some *new style* emoticons etc.

How can I fix this?

**Update:**

This happens everywhere (Twitter, Facebook, you name it). I'm not using special fonts or have changed something font-related on my system (Windows 7, 64 bit). Am I wrong assuming this should just work?

**Update 2:**

This drives me insane. There are still so many characters that are not displaying.

Example (wrapped gift):

[image: Using Segoe UI Symbol explicitly via dev tools]

As you can see, Chrome is not displaying the character by default. Only when I explicitly set the font to Segoe UI Symbol, it does. Why is Chrome not using the font as a fallback automatically?

How can I make Chrome recognize the Segoe UI Symbol font?

Comment: maybe try this http://gschoppe.com/blog/fixing-unicode-support-in-google-chrome/  says "Code2000, Code2001, and Code2002 are three true-type fonts that were designed by James Kass in 2008.  They are known as a Pan-Unicode font set, designed to contain as many glyphs as possible.  They were available for free, from Kass’ website, until it went down in 2011."   and he gives a link  to te zip http://gschoppe.com/projects/fbformat/includes/unicodefont.zip

Comment: He says "download the ZIP, extract the files, and copy them into your fonts directory in control panel.  After a quick restart, Chrome will have full unicode support"

Comment: @barlop Well, I had that in my search results, too. I wasn't all too keen about installing some fonts from a foreign site, but well... it worked. Thank you. You can post it as an answer so I can accept/upvote. ;)

Comment: Code2000 etc. do not provide *full* Unicode support.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Good to know. Do you know how to improve the Unicode support?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela  err dude, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font  "No single 'Unicode font' includes all the characters defined in the present revision of ISO 10646 (Unicode) standard, as it is continually adding more & more"

Comment: @barlop, no single font can cover even all the current Unicode characters, due to font technologies. A few fonts combined could do that, but Code200x don’t do that.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I never said it did. I don't see the purpose of your comment to me if you are just repeated what I quoted from wikipedia to you. Earlier you said that font didn't provide "full unicode support" (as if it's a limitation with that font and that another font might). I pointed you to Wikipedia to show you that No Font Does.  Now you are agreeing with me. And I don't see the purpose of you saying this font doesn't(as if it's a fault with this font), when you know that no font does.

Comment: @barlop, you called them “Pan-Unicode font set” and quoted text saying “Chrome will have full unicode support”. I corrected this by saying that they do not provide full Unicode support.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela oh quoting that guy's blog, you're right, I didn't spot that. And you're reight re "pan-unicode" This from gnu.org "Many arguments have appeared in recent years against fonts that cover many ranges of Unicode (sometimes incorrectly referred to as “pan-Unicode” fonts)."

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela And that blog gets the year wrong too, the font was created in 1998 not 2008.

Comment: Though re me,  re my gnu quote, pan-unicode probably isn't a wrong term..that's probably just stallman being odd.  it's more that fonts are so-called pan-unicode. Or that it's understood that pan-unicode doesn't mean all. But just a lot.

Comment: I have the same issue in Chrome. This page http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146795/what-is-the-ipa-for-trade shows boxes in Chrome but has no problem in Fx on the same box

Comment: @mplungjan This page has no issues for me. I have the "Code2000" as suggested by barlop installed.

Comment: I wonder if I have to restart windows...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.fontspace.com/james-kass/code2000 (3.73MB)

> Code2000 font — Created in 1998 by James Kass .. Code2000 is a work-in-process. It currently (Version 1.171) has over 60000 glyphs.
>
> Although it is more-or-less readable at 12 - 18 point, it is much
>   clearer at about 24 point. Some of the dingbats should be at least 36
>   point. With font- smoothing it looks good at normal sizes.

There is a blog that mentions it
http://gschoppe.com/blog/fixing-unicode-support-in-google-chrome/
But the blog gets lots of things wrong in its description. (See comments on your question, for some examples. But his description doesn't matter)

You found the instructions mentioned on the blog worked, which was to extract the zip into the fonts folder in control panel and restart chrome.

http://gschoppe.com/projects/fbformat/includes/unicodefont.zip

Answer (score 4):

Boxes or squares showing up in place of actual glyphs is a side-effect of the font you are using not having that Unicode character incorporated.  Try looking for a font with a more complete Unicode implementation.

Comment: Doesn't the browser check other system fonts if they have the missing glyphs?

Comment: I was going to add that you can try and check [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95416?hl=en) and try and change the default font.

Comment: @kleinfreund, my understanding is that it will check other typefaces in the same family, but won't go beyond that.  So if your site is in Arial, it won't use Gothic glyphs.