# Chrome Unicode Displaying Issues

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, fonts, unicode

How do I fix `Chrome` so that it shows unicode characters like  properly?

Here's how it looks like:

[image]

Here's how it should look like:

[image]

Neither Firefox nor Internet Explorer have this issue. Please post a step-by-step or tutorial or link me to a working one.

Comment: Appears to be answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/705503/several-unicode-characters-are-not-displaying-on-many-big-sites-like-this

Comment: @JNevill: It doesn't work for me